# Dynamically include a table column names in a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `select` defined in a stored procedure that has a hard coded table column name in it `PoliticsId`

Defined as:

```
 [PoliticsId] [int] NOT NULL.
```

It holds integer values.

`@a_ProfileCategoryId` comes in a value = 1.

```
          SELECT SelectionId    
                 ,COUNT(SelectionId) AS Count
                 ,[Description]
          FROM dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections a
          JOIN dbo.UserProfile b ON SelectionId = PoliticsId
          WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = @a_ProfileCategoryId )
          GROUP BY SelectionId
                   ,[Description]
          ORDER BY COUNT(SelectionId)
```

It works fine.

```
SelectionId Count   Description
1           1       Conservative
4           4       Independent
```

---

I now want to make it dynamic so I can pass in a similar 'column name' to it as a parameter `@a_columnName`.

So the parameter would contain a value of say 'PoliticsId'.

`@a_ProfileCategoryId` comes in a value = 4.

```
          SELECT SelectionId    
                         ,COUNT(SelectionId) AS Count
                         ,[Description]
          FROM dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections a
          JOIN dbo.UserProfile ON SelectionId = @a_columnName
          WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = @a_ProfileCategoryId )
          GROUP BY SelectionId
                              ,[Description]
          ORDER BY COUNT(SelectionId)
```

How do I code for that?

---

I tried dynamic SQL and solved coding for the 'column name'. It works.

```
          DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
                       ,@columnName varchar(50)

          SET @columnName = 'PoliticsId'

          SELECT @sql =
                ' SELECT SelectionId    
                         ,COUNT(SelectionId) AS Count
                         ,[Description]
          FROM dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections a
          JOIN dbo.UserProfile ON SelectionId = '+@columnName+'
          WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = 4)
          GROUP BY SelectionId
                              ,[Description]
          ORDER BY COUNT(SelectionId)'

        -- Execute the dynamic sql.
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

---

However, now when I try to remove the hard coding of the `ProfileCategoryId = 4`,

```
          DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
                      ,@columnName varchar(50)
                      ,@ProfileCategoryId int

          SET @columnName = 'PoliticsId'
          SET @ProfileCategoryId = 4

          SELECT @sql =
                ' SELECT SelectionId    
                         ,COUNT(SelectionId) AS Count
                         ,[Description]
          FROM dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections a
          JOIN dbo.UserProfile ON SelectionId = '+@columnName+'
          WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = '+@ProfileCategoryId+')
          GROUP BY SelectionId
                              ,[Description]
          ORDER BY COUNT(SelectionId)'

        -- Execute the dynamic sql.
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

I get:

```
      Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' SELECT SelectionId    
                         ,COUNT(SelectionId) AS Count
                         ,[Description]
          FROM dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections a
          JOIN dbo.UserProfile ON SelectionId = PoliticsId
          WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = ' to data type int.
```

---

I tried casting.

```
          DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
                       ,@columnName varchar(50)
                       ,@ProfileCategoryId int
                       ,@CastedProfileCategoryId varchar(MAX)

          SET @columnName = 'PoliticsId'
          SET @ProfileCategoryId = 4

          SELECT @CastedProfileCategoryId = CAST(@ProfileCategoryId AS VARCHAR)

          SELECT @sql =
                ' SELECT SelectionId    
                ,COUNT(SelectionId) AS Count
                ,[Description]
          FROM dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections a
          JOIN dbo.UserProfile ON SelectionId = '+@columnName+'
          WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = @CastedProfileCategoryId )
          GROUP BY SelectionId
                              ,[Description]
          ORDER BY COUNT(SelectionId)'

        -- Execute the dynamic sql.
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

I get:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@CastedProfileCategoryId".

Comment: I think you'll need [dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/) for this

Comment: I added in dynamic sql. Almost there...but not quite.

Comment: you need to cast @ProfileCategoryId as a varchar before you can add it to the string, I think. Otherwise it treats the `+` as a mathematical operation (instead of a string concatenation operation) and tries to calculate the sum of the string and the int...which clearly won't work.

Comment: I tried that. Declared the variable as varchar. SELECT @CastedProfileCategoryId = CAST(@ProfileCategoryId AS VARCHAR). Replaced accordingly, but I now get: I get: Must declare the scalar variable "@CastedProfileCategoryId".

Comment: Well then you need to declare it. But you don't actually need a separate variable at all, just do the cast inline after the `+`

Comment: Ok. Now it works.I had removed the + signs before. Now there back.    WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = '+CAST(@ProfileCategoryId AS VARCHAR)+' )

Comment: How do I give you credit?

Comment: I will add a proper answer in a bit. Then you can mark it as accepted, which gives me the credit. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/) for this:

```
      DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
              ,@columnName varchar(50)
              ,@ProfileCategoryId int

      SET @columnName = 'PoliticsId'
      SET @ProfileCategoryId = 4

      SELECT @sql =
            ' SELECT SelectionId    
            ,COUNT(SelectionId) AS Count
            ,[Description]
      FROM dbo.ProfileCategoryAllSelections a
      JOIN dbo.UserProfile ON SelectionId = '+ CAST(@ProfileCategoryId AS VARCHAR) +'
      WHERE ( ProfileCategoryId = @CastedProfileCategoryId )
      GROUP BY SelectionId
                          ,[Description]
      ORDER BY COUNT(SelectionId)'

    -- Execute the dynamic sql.
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```